# AJAX POST request to server not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, post

I am building an app using node.js and I have the following POST request:

```
var api = express.Router();

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/login/",
        data: context,
        success: function(data, status) {
            console.log('succeeded!!');
        },
        error: function(data, status, res) {
            console.log('error :(');
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
```

Server side API:

```
api.post('/api/login/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('login api hit'); //does not console log
});
```

The problem is the server does not receive the POST request. I checked by console logging text on the server side, but it does not return anything...

Anyone know what might be going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `api`? A mounted router? Your main app?

Comment: api is my router middleware. I updated my question to include its declaration @mscdex

Comment: What do the browser's developer tools say? Are there any messages in the Console tab? Can you see the request in the Network tab?

Comment: @user1547174 How are you mounting the `api` router though? Are you doing something like `app.use('/api', api)` or perhaps `app.use(api)`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the ajax call. Try to test the server by executing this script:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8080,
  // if it's not localhost, put 'hostname' instead host and port
  //hostname: 'some_url.net',
  path: '/api/login/',
  method: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json'
};

function sendRequest( data ) {
    var req = http.request( options, function( res ) {
        console.log( 'STATUS: ' + res.statusCode );
        //console.log( 'HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers) );
        res.setEncoding( 'utf8' );
        res.on( 'data', function( chunk ) {
            console.log( 'BODY: ' + chunk );
        });
        req.on('error', function( e ) {
            console.log( 'problem with request: ' + e.message );
        });
    });
    // write data to request body
    req.write( JSON.stringify(data) );
    req.end();
}

sendRequest( {"some":"data"} );
```

Hope it helps you to figure out what is going wrong.